# Can Config::IniFiles read files with errors?

Tags: perl, ini

I use the following code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Config::IniFiles;

my $cfg = Config::IniFiles->new( -file => 'SomeFilePath.ini' );
```

Then I got errors inside the table `Config::IniFiles::errors`. For example, something like

```
 Line 33 in file SomeFilePath.ini is mal-formed:
 HKR,,,,,%SOMEVARIABLE%
```

How can I skip badly formatted section/lines and read the others ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: That module cannot do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Config::IniFiles parses Ini files. If your files isn't a valid Ini file then Config::IniFiles won't be able to parse it.

But you can check whether the file is valid and give the user an error telling them what to fix.

```
my $cfg = Config::IniFiles->new( -file => 'SomeFilePath.ini' );

unless ($cfg) {
  die "Errors in your config file:\n" .
      join("\n", @Config::IniFiles::errors) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: This should be `join(_, _)`, not `join(_; _)`

Comment: @Synthead: Thanks! And congratulations for being the first person to spot it in three and a half years.